# Vue component isnt visible in html

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I just started with Vue.js in school and in my first assignment I´m going to print a h2 from a vue component but I cant get it to work. I have created the vue component as shown below.

```
   var app = new Vue({
       el: '#app'

   })

   Vue.component('titleMsg', {
       template: '<h1>{{ title }}</h1>',
       data: {
           title: 'Vue startsida'
       }
   })
```

And my html code here.

```
   <body>
           <div id="app">
               <titleMsg></titleMsg>
           </div>
           <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
           <script src="main.js"></script>
       </body>
```

Can someone please tell me what i´m missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use directive name format(kebabCase) for component name and "component’s data option must be a function" as per official documentation
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

```
Instead, a component’s data option must be a function, so that each instance can maintain an independent copy of the returned data object:
```

sample working code for reference-

```js
 Vue.component('titleMsg', {
       template: '<h1>{{ title }}</h1>',
       data:function() {
         return {
           title: 'Vue startsida'
       }
       }
   })

new Vue({ el: '#app' })
```

```css
#app div{
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<body>
           <div id="app">
               <title-msg></title-msg>
           </div>
       </body>
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/GRRereG

Answer (score 1):

It's not showing because `data` should be a function that returns an object...

```
   data() {
       return {
        title: 'Vue startsida'
       }
   }
```

*Also*, kebab-case the name of the component in the markup..

```
<div id="app">
    <title-msg></title-msg>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/LwKtkn7VUX

Comment: thats not snake-case though (its kebab-case) :)